# How to use GAE channel API when there are network disconnections ?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I want to use the Google App-Engine Channel API and send messages from server to client.
I'am worried about possible network disconnections.

What's happen by example if the client is not reachable from the server during a certain time ?
Is there a error message on server side ?

I saw that we can configure a special url for disconnection (/_ah/channel/disconnected/) but when this url is called? I think it's only when the disconnection is called using a function on client-side ?

My concern actually is : what if the client miss a important message of update ? Should i manage a acknowledgement for each message sent by the channel API ? (ex : rest call after each message sent ) ?

When the client come back to life (reconnection to the network), i will have to sent again all waiting messages ?

Thanks for your return if you already have implemented something similar.